# Can't browse to second site collection (except locally)

Tags: 2010, site-collection

I have created a new site collection in the same web application, using "Support" to give me the URL "http://someserver/sites/Support"
I can browse this locally on the server, but when I try to browse from my desktop I get 404'd?

I can still see the "parent" site collection locally and remotely, and I have full permissions to the Support collection.

Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try browsing to: http://someserver/sites/Support/_layouts/settings.aspx If you can access this, then you probably have an unpublished welcomes page.

Comment: Error 
File Not Found.

Comment: http://blog.fpweb.net/troubleshooting-sharepoint-file-not-found-error/

Comment: This lead me to the issue: The servers name was different from the name used in the DNS.  Added an Alternate Access Mapping and everything now works.  The error I finally found was:
Alternate access mappings have not been configured.  Users or services are accessing the site http://tst-sp2010 with the URL http://tst-sharepoint.  This may cause incorrect links to be stored or returned to users.  If this is expected, add the URL http://tst-sharepoint as an AAM response URL.  For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=114854"/>